# How to attach an icon next to a link using an ending selectors?

Tags: html, css

The issue I'm having is that my link is being placed over the icon, so that the icon is in the background, not next to it as I would like. How would you write this so that the icon would be to the left of the link?

HTML:

```
<p><a href="http://www.scholastic.com/thehungergames/media/hungergames-chapter1.pdf" title="Book  Sample">Hunger Games, Chapter 1</a></p>
```

CSS:

```css
a[href $=".pdf"] {
    background: url('image.png') no-repeat center left; 
    padding-left 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code and it seems to work just fine..

[SEE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qtgye/kv3px3cd/)

```
a[href$=".pdf"] {
  background: url('http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/cute-cat-l.jpg') no-repeat center left; 
  padding-left: 25px; /* you forgot the colon here */
  background-size: auto 100%; /* make the background size 100% of the height of the anchor link */
}
```